# Possible to open a text file in a MYSQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, file-io

Is it possible to open and read from a text file in a MYSQL stored procedure? I have a text file with a list of about 50k telephone numbers, and want to write a stored procedure that will open the file, read the 50k lines and store it as rows in a table. I cannot load the file directly using LOAD IN FILE as the table has additional columns that I have to set.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a job for MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: use LOAD DATA INFILE to write to a temporary table then copy what you need from there and drop it.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used LOAD IN FILE. Apparently you can set which columns get populated by using the SET keyword:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/temp/input_file.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE TEST.TEST_INSERT (INSERT_FIELD) SET VERSION=1, LIST_ID=ID_GEN(), CREATE_DATE=NOW(), CREATE_BY='TESTUSER';
```